# IDisposable Example

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

I am looking for an example in which shows dispose pattern of .net with managed and un-managed resourced are allocated. In every text book only code snippets are shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of .net 2.0 it's advised to use `SafeHandle`s to manage resources, as detailed on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx).

---

MSDN has an example on its [`IDisposable.Dispose` Method page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), although as per comments, **this is outdated**.

Comment: Unfortunately the pattern used in this example is obsolete. To free unmanaged resources you should not use a normal finalizer, but a critical finalizer. The problem with this pattern is that it doesn't always work correctly when unloading AppDomains.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, edited. I assume the MSDN article does it correctly.

Comment: I think that code was the best available solution in .net 1.x, but should be avoided since .net 2. `SafeHandle`s and critical finalization is the way to go. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx

Comment: +1 I really dislike the IDisposable pattern's recommendation to use a Boolean to indicate whether one should handle both managed and unmanaged resources, or just unmanaged resources.  If a class would hold both managed (self-cleaning) resources and unmanaged resources needing finalization, that's a pretty strong indication that the unmanaged resources should be wrapped in their own classes, turning them into managed resources.  Using Dispose(Boolean) as an overridable version of Dispose not attached directly to the interface, using the Boolean simply to change the signature...

Comment: ...may make inheritance cleaner (avoiding "re-implementation" warnings), but I'm not really sure it's better since it would seem to add another virtual function call.

Answer (score 2):

I think that all you have to know is very well described in the following article "**Digging into IDisposable**" on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx